# A spread argument must either have a tuple type typescript error, way too often

Tags: typescript

I come to this error way too often, and I can't solve it now.

```
src/graphics.ts:105:55 - error TS2556: A spread argument must either have a
tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.

105       _queue.forEach((_: any[]) => draw_ctx(this.ctx, ..._))
                                                          ~~~~
```

Here's the code:

```
export default class Graphics {

  _queues: any

  constructor(readonly ctx: number) {
    this._queues = {}
  }

  flush() {
      Object.keys(this._queues).map(color => {
      let _queue = this._queues[color]
      _queue.forEach((_: any[]) => draw_ctx(this.ctx, ..._))
    })
  }
}


function draw_ctx(ctx: number, _f: any, r: number, x: number, y: number, w: number, h: number, ...rest: any) {
    console.log('hello')
}
```

Here's the `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["ESNext", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    //"noUnusedLocals": true,
    //"noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKApgHgDg9gTgFwAQBMwDMCGBXANsgY10wGcSkBxOTKACwEsDyBvUUJJAfQEdsw+SALiSYAdgE82IDgRiiSCONgIJ4ACjhhMKObnFIVEYaOwBbAEZg4ASiStpHJAgYkAdDz4CkAXjsBfdiQAkED0XGwSWjVbe0dHAHlzACswFVcAazBxEjVnejcPfjASa1dTGjVZXHgfAD47QLjcMGRCvh8nF3deIpIAbSr4AF1GxzawV3R4AFFMAii1TmExcT6h2296lGoAd05DXK7DABokV3POa2tRv2uHYOCpdGxRFXo5VF39hAhKn+MzJY4KdOOhlhJTnAARYrKcjEgTDDgUhxNCgacdmjYUhaFjkedXJoFODxDFRrJ5DBmq5qgBzNQAcloYFw1QZdz8QA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because an array is not a tuple. A tuple is an array with a predefined number of elements.

TypeScript doesn't know if you have the correct amount of elements in that array to fulfill all the required arguments in the `draw_ctx` function.

TypeScript is simply asking for the `_` argument to have a signature that matches the `draw_ctx` arguments, like so:

```js
_queue.forEach((_:[any, number, number, number, number, number, ...any]) => draw_ctx(this.ctx, ..._))
```

Note how I defined an array with a predefined amount of elements.

Addendum: Still, this code needs a lot of improvements, like: instead of casting the `_queue` array type, you should define the `this._queues` type properly, so when you work with `this._queues` you will be forced to always follow the correct types:

```js
export default class Graphics {

  _queues:{[color:string]:[any, number, number, number, number, number, ...any][]}

  constructor(readonly ctx: number) {
    this._queues = {}
  }

  flush() {
      Object.keys(this._queues).map(color => {
      let _queue = this._queues[color]
      _queue.forEach((_) => draw_ctx(this.ctx, ..._))
    })
  }
}


function draw_ctx(ctx: number, _f: any, r: number, x: number, y: number, w: number, h: number, ...rest: any) {
    console.log('hello')
}
```

[link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKApgHgDg9gTgFwAQBMwDMCGBXANsgY10wGcSkBxOTKACwEsDyBvUUJJAfQEdsw+SALmYBtAjFzxBJBHHoA7AOYBdQSMzyAngBok87AFsARmDi79x0+cMmzem1fuW7AOjcbNykcoC+bEBzi8jJw2AQI8AAUcGCYKDDyuJpI4RCCTrYAlEisARxICAwkLjx8AkgAvDl+eTXsSOi42CS0kdm5+fkA8kYAVmDhLgDWYJokkYX0xaX8YCSZLgY0keKScJUAfDn1nbhgyDN8lQVFJbyzJGIS8Mo7+YdgLujwAKKYBK2RnNkVWyjUAHdOKkJqdUro3CVMpk7j4YbVQHUQKB0Nh5OF6AlUIDgQgICs8ekLLZdJx0OkPLo4ESHHY0hlHJoac5dADmSSkLR2Y5ITEZBStO07kESBJHpJFJEAOS0MC4SRS+E+IA)

In your code adding `this._queues["crash"] = "this will crash the program in runtime"` works, but in my code it shows an error.

Remember: `any` in TypeScript is bad. ALWAYS avoid it, and your code will be strongly typed. Using `any` you can have the same problems that you have in JavaScript, making TypeScript a non-sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the type of `_` is `any[]` and typescript cannot match the correct number of parameters for `draw_ctx`. For example, this works:

```js
draw_ctx(this.ctx, 'foo', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..._)
```

You can always disable this rule for a specific line like this:

```js
// @ts-ignore: A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.
draw_ctx(this.ctx, ..._)
```

Comment: Disabling rules is the worse thing you can do to solve a problem. Is just a workaround.

Comment: This is useful, for my purposes thanks.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález of course, but judging from the fact that the argument is already typed explicitly as `any`, it might be inferred that type checking is not desired for this piece of code. Usually the `any` type will prevent type-checking, but in this case we need an additional tsignore rule.